# C# WPF изменение стиля кнопки через код C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю приложение для практики (обучаюсь), мне нужно создать кнопку для WPF не используя XAML, просто через сам C#, но кнопка должна быть не стандартная, а со стилем от material Desing, не совсем понимаю как это сделать, вроде мой код работает, но нужный стиль не встает, по умолчанию кнопка от material desing квадратная, мне нужна круглая, я прописываю код круглого стиля (копируя из готовой кнопки из XAML) и не работает..

код подобной кнопки в XAML:

```
<Button Margin="5" Click="Продукты_Click" x:Name="Продукты" ToolTip="Продукты"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Background="White" BorderBrush="White" >
  <Image Source="/icomproduct.png"/>
</Button>
```

как лучше прописать все свойства этой кнопки через сам C# ? особенно интересует подключение данного стиля, т.к. создание самой кнопки и подключение ToolTip вопросов не вызывает.

```
string nameCategory = textNewCotegory.Text.Trim();
Button newBotton = new Button();
newBotton.Name = nameCategory;
newBotton.ToolTip = "Новая Категория";
newBotton.Style = Resources["MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton"] 
as Style;
newButtonList.Children.Add(newBotton);
```

причем после такого кода кнопка создается вообще без стиля, хотя само окно подключено к стилю, если создать кнопку через XAML то стиль есть, через код С# почему то нет..

[image: какая кнопка получается у меня]

Comment: Вы не должны вообще хотеть подобное в WPF проекте. Думаете там XAML просто так придумали, чтоб его все обходили стороной? WPF - это в первую очередь привязки (Binding) и XAML. Если вы их не используете, то зачем тогда вам WPF? Используйте WinForms. В вашем проекте не должно быть обращения к контролам через код, в XAML не должно быть `x:Name`, ваш проект должен работать так, будто у него вообще нет UI.

Comment: ну ситуации же разные бывают, вот мне например нужно сделать возможность создавать пользовательские категории, саму категорию я сохраняю в SQL как название самой категории, сама категория у меня отображается в виде кнопки (т.к. это удобно), соответственно чтобы пользовательская категория сохранилась, каждый раз идет проверка на наличие таковых и их нужно создать с таким же стилем как и остальные встроенные категории..

Comment: Ситуации разные, да, только они все решаются одинаково. Повторю, вы не должны хотеть в WPF проекте создавать контролы, или даже банально дергать их через код. В WPF, при помощи привязок, данные отделяются от UI, в контролах не хранят вообще ничего. Вот ваша задача выше: делаете класс, в нем публичные свойства, например `public class Category { public string Name {get;set;} }`, далее делаете коллекцию этих классов, например `public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories {get;} = new() { ... }`, задаете окну `DataContext` на класс, где коллекция

Comment: Остается XAML `<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}"><ItemsControl.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate<Button Content={Binding Name}/><DataTemplate><ItemsControl.ItemTemplate></ItemsControl>`. Вот и все, у вас на экране будут кнопки, где данные будут в коллекции, а в XAML будет дизайн, не более.

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы уточнить, а проверяли ли вы эту строку кода на null? Есть ощущение, что стиль просто не может найтись.

```
newBotton.Style = Resources["MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton"]
```

Стили прописывать в code behind конечно можно, но не стоит. Если очень хочется - то никаких сложностей в этом нет. Смотрите код **XAML** и создавайте подобные объекты в вашем **C#** коде. Для начала делаете класс стиля:

```
Style style = new(typeof(Button));
```

Далее этому стилю задаете необходимые вам свойства. Например переопределим у кнопки стандартный **Foreground**:

```
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red));
```

В данном случае свойство `Foreground` у кнопки наследуется от его предка **Control**, поэтому написал так `Control.ForegroundProperty`, хотя можно писать и `Button.ForegroundProperty`. Разницы нет.